# How can I get the row and column of an edited cell from NSTableView using Xamarin.Mac?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am building a **Xamarin.Mac** application, and one of the `ViewControllers` contains an `NSTableView`. I have successfully been able to populate the table view, but I would like the user to be able to edit some of the cell contents.

Functionally, I am also able to get the cell editable. However, I cannot extract the row and the column for the edited cell. **Is this possible?**

I have the `NSTableViewDelegate` code:

```
public override NSView GetViewForItem(NSTableView tableView, NSTableColumn tableColumn, nint row)
{
    // Get the data
    var Data = this._dataSource.DataRecords[(int)row];

    NSTextField view = (NSTextField)tableView.MakeView(CellIdentifier, this);
    if (view == null)
    {
        view = new NSTextField();
        view.Identifier = CellIdentifier;
        view.BackgroundColor = NSColor.Clear;
        view.Bordered = false;
        view.Selectable = true;
        view.Editable = true;
        view.EditingEnded += this.EditingEnded;
    }

    // Setup view based on the column selected
    if(tableColumn.Title.Equals(string.Empty)) {
        view.IntValue = Convert.ToInt16(row);
    }
    else {
        view.StringValue = Data.Get(tableColumn.Title).ToString();
    }

    return view;
}

void EditingEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I can get a reference to the correct, edited, NSTextField 
    //   with the following line.
    var textField = ((NSNotification)sender).Object as NSTextField;

    // However, HERE, I would like to know what row and column was edited so 
    //  that I can update my source data with the user-made change.
}
```

**Does anyone know how to use this logic to get the edited cell's position in the `NSTableView`?**

I am using Xamarin.Mac, but I assume the same logic/question would apply if I was using Swift or Objective-C for my app. I'd happily take an answer in either of those languages as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the column and row for any NSView in your NSTableView by using the NSTableView's:

- RowForView
- ColumnForView

#### Example:

```
var textField = ((NSNotification)sender).Object as NSTextField;
var row = someTableView.RowForView(textField);
var column = someTableView.ColumnForView(textField);
```

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1526732-rowforview?language=objc
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1529415-columnforview?language=objc

Comment: Great! Yup, this works exactly as I need it to. Thanks for the help; I certainly learned something.

Comment: Np, happy `Xamarin.Mac`'ing ;-)